Pandas check for records for a lag before a certain date range of interest and exclude
I want to check for a date range of interest but the problem is that one of my constraints is dependant on records before data range.
My example is that I'm interested in novice race records from 2018 onwards but I want to be able to check did a given driver_id have a novice race before this date range or not as I need to check what the 2 first races (check whether both handicap, both graded, combo form the race_type column) are by using groupby(["driver_id"]) and .head(2) within the date range.
The problem is that I'm not accounting for potential novice races that happen before the date range.
Original DF
| performance | performance_date | race_code | race_type | driver_id | season |
|-------------|------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|--------|
| 1           | 2017-05-04       | novice    | handicap  | 1         | 17     |
| 2           | 2017-06-09       | novice    | graded    | 1         | 17     |
| 3           | 2017-05-09       | open      | handicap  | 2         | 17     |
| 4           | 2018-07-10       | novice    | handicap  | 2         | 18     |
| 5           | 2018-07-17       | novice    | handicap  | 2         | 18     |
| 6           | 2019-05-09       | novice    | graded    | 2         | 19     |
| 7           | 2017-08-10       | novice    | graded    | 1         | 17     |
| 8           | 2018-09-09       | novice    | graded    | 1         | 18     |
| 9           | 2018-09-28       | open      | graded    | 1         | 18     |

Desired DF
| performance | performance_date | race_code | race_type | driver_id | season |   |
|-------------|------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|--------|---|
| 4           | 2018-07-10       | novice    | handicap  | 2         | 18     |   |
| 5           | 2018-07-17       | novice    | handicap  | 2         | 18     |   |
| 6           | 2019-05-09       | novice    | graded    | 2         | 19     |   |

So I would classify this runner_id in a handicap-2 group to represent the first 2 races it performed in when it didn't have a novice race ran before the date range.

Not very clear to me. Why there is no driver_id 1 in the desired df? if a driver is novice before 2018 you ignore him?

Yes, more a less but I want to get a list of horses that have had a novice race before 2018 and exclude and maybe use additional field race_type also.
